# how to select column table dynamically with column condition

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to write a  query that's allows me to get number of columns dynamically according to condition, this is what i am looking for :

```
select column1,column2,column3 , columncond from table , if : columncond = 'true'
select column4,column5 , columncond from table ,if : columncond = 'false'
```

how i can make this logic in one query and getting my result dynamically according the value of columncond (true or false), i am using oracle.

thanks in advance.

Comment: The number of columns needs to be known when the query is parsed; you can't have a single SQL query which varies the number of columns in the select list. (You can use dynamic SQL, which defers parsing, or have your client build the query dynamically; I don't think that's what you want though). How will the caller know how many columns to expect and how to process them? Can you include dummy null columns  so the select lists have the same number (and types) of columns?

Comment: Hi alex, thanks for your response i solved  my problem by selecting all column, and making some if else in my client.

Answer (score 3):

You can not have a single query wich returns different rows with different number of columns; all the rows of a single query must have the same number and type of columns.

What you could do is write a query returning a fixed number of columns, but with NULL in the columns you do not want, based on some condition.

For example:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN columncond = 'true' THEN column1 ELSE column4 END,
       CASE WHEN columncond = 'true' THEN column2 ELSE column5 END,
       CASE WHEN columncond = 'true' THEN column3 ELSE NULL END,
       columncond
  FROM your_table
```

Comment: It seems that the OP wants a query with a different number of columns in different rows, within a single query; editing my answer to clarify

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for your response i solved  my problem by selecting all columns, and making some if else in my client.

Answer (score 0):

Use where

```
select column1,column2,column3 , columncond 
from table 
where columncond = 'true';

select column4,column5 , columncond 
from table  
where columncond = 'false';
```